# Arithmetic-static Variables error

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

public class Arithmectic {

    double mealCost;
    int tipPercent;
    int taxPercent;

    public Arithmectic(double inMeal, int inTip, int inTax){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    inMeal = scan.nextDouble();
    mealCost = inMeal;

    inTip = scan.nextInt();
    tipPercent = inTip;

    inTax = scan.nextInt();
    taxPercent = inTax;

    }

    public void printValues(){

    System.out.println(mealCost);
    System.out.println(tipPercent);
    System.out.println(taxPercent);
    }

 public static void main(String[] args) {

     Arithmectic rest = new Arithmectic(mealCost, tipPercent, taxPercent);


 }
}
```

**Am having an issue with

```
Arithmectic rest = new Arithmectic(mealCost, tipPercent, taxPercent);
```

Can someone help me and explain why am i having this error ?**

Comment: `new Arithmectic(mealCost, tipPercent, taxPercent);` these variables you´re trying to pass there are class members of `Arithmetic` and as though don´t exist in the scope of `public static main(String[])`. You should probably redesign the `Arithmectic` constructor to not input the variables with the scanner, but just assign the parametr => class members. Another method should actually read the input, and pass the values it did read as parameter to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

If your `main` is in the same class (i.e. `Arithmectic`) you are trying to access the instance variables of that class in order to pass them to the constructor of that class.

It makes no sense and cannot be done anyway (you can't access instance variables from a static context).

If your constructor is initializing the members from user input, it doesn't need to get those parameters from the outside.

That said, it would make more sense to get the user input in your `main` and pass it to the constructor:

```
public Arithmectic(double inMeal, int inTip, int inTax){
    mealCost = inMeal;
    tipPercent = inTip;
    taxPercent = inTax; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    double inMeal = scan.nextDouble();
    int inTip = scan.nextInt();
    int inTax = scan.nextInt();
    Arithmectic rest = new Arithmectic(inMeal, inTip, inTax);
}
```